# Formatting not taken into account by macro argument

Tags: formatting

I'm building a macro to output the version at the end of a document.

This is a simple macro, it just put the argument after "Version: ", in gray and in italic.

Here is the MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Insert the project version
\newcommand\insertVersion[1][]{%
    \vfill\hfill%
    \footnotesize{%
        \textcolor{blue}{%
            Version: \textit{#1}%
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]


\insertVersion{1.1.0}
\end{document}
```

However, for some reason it fails. The formatting doesn't apply to the argument :
[image: MWE output]

I'm sure I'm missing a dumb thing, but I can't wrap my head around this issue...

Comment: You are declaring the command with an optional argument which is by default empty; remove the `[]` in your code. Note also the `\footnotesize` is a switch and it does not take an argument.

Comment: Indeed. I'll let you post the answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
\newcommand\insertVersion[1][]{...}
```

you are defining a macro `\insertVersion` which takes an *optional* parameter which is empty by default. When you use it as `\insertVersion{1.1.0}` the optional parameter is not given, so the code expands as it were effectively

```
\vfill\hfill\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{Version: \textit{}}}{1.1.0}
```

and you get a blue *Version:* followed by an empty italic text. The version number is still in `\footnotesize` because this macro takes no argument but is actually a switch. Since it not in a group, the font change effectively leaks outside your intended use and still prints the version number in smaller font.

A better definition would be

```
\newcommand*{\insertVersion}[1]{%
    \vfill\hfill
        \textcolor{blue}{%
            \footnotesize Version: \textit{#1}%
        }%
}
```

(There is room for improvement: this might fail if the macro is expanded at a page break.)